# How to add TableRow dynamically to the TableLayout

Tags: android

I need to add `TableRow` which consists of several different `Views` dynamically to the `TableLayout` but have this `TableRow`'s inflated from my `layout.xml`. Please advice how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Calling [`addView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29) on the `TableLayout`, passing it the `TableRow` and a [`TableLayout.LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.LayoutParams.html), should work.

Comment: The point is to inflate the `TableRow` from xml and then add it.

Comment: @silk: Inflate the `TableRow` via a `LayoutInflater`, then call `addView()` on the `TableLayout`, passing it the inflated `TableRow` and a `TableRow.LayoutParams`.